# How to calculate within a factor in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Apologies if this question is trivially easy, I'm still learning Tableau.

I have data where the variables `Set` and `Subset` are arranged by week (`W1` to `W52`) and by Source (`A` or `B`). So if I put `Week` into Rows and create the calculated fields

```
SUM(Set)
SUM(Subset)
Rate = {INCLUDE Source: SUM(Subset) / SUM(Set)}
```

I get data that look like this:

```
Week     SUM(Set)      SUM(Subset)       Rate
        A      B       A        B      A      B
W1    1234    123     567      56    45.95% 45.53%
```

So far, so good. But what I really want is the percentage difference between Rate(A) and Rate(B) by week:

```
Diff = (Rate.A - Rate.B) / Rate.B
```

I could do this in a second if I were using Excel or R, but I can't seem to figure out how Tableau does it. Help?

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in table calculation "Percent Difference" , you can deploy it using compute using Table across and relative to previous. For that you need to have continuous measures.
Something like this will be the calculation-:

```
(ZN(SUM([Quantity])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Quantity])), -1)) / ABS(LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Quantity])), -1))
```

Create two different for "Set" & "Subset"